# Can not download dependencies

Tags: git, go, bitbucket

I have a project with several dependencies from private repositories on bitbucket when I type command go build . I get this error

> unrecognized import path "bitbucket.xxx.xx/xx/x" x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I have tried several things such as adding token

> git config --global http.extraheader token

Configure to ssh

> git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"

but it does not work.

Comment: a) `bitbucket.xxx.xx != bitbucket.org` b) Your bitbucket server uses a self-signed certificate. Get back to the old url and use `git config http.sslVerify false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding using an HTTPS URL, note that HTTP transport had possible allocator/deallocator mismatch, which has been corrected, with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020).

So if you were using Git 2.24, `http.extraheader` would not have worked anyway.

See [commit 4d17fd2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d17fd253fbba05c643593bcb86515683badb03f) (06 Nov 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bad5ed3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bad5ed39cdd84953f935f4442dd92fe3f7afafc2), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`remote-curl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d17fd253fbba05c643593bcb86515683badb03f): unbreak http.extraHeader with custom allocators
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> In [93b980e58f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93b980e58f5624ee4e3b2dc0d0babaa97ef66d19) ("`http`: use xmalloc with cURL", 2019-08-15, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2e524ecf396722020e85b39d7b5e83d7c95ec24) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c86140027f4a0d2caaa3ab4bd8bfc5ce3c11c8a)), we started to ask cURL to use `xmalloc()`, and if compiled with nedmalloc, that means implicitly a different allocator than the system one.
>
> Which means that all of cURL's allocations and releases now `_need`_ to use that allocator.
>
> However, the `http_options()` function used `slist_append()` to add any configured extra HTTP header(s) `_before`_ asking cURL to use `xmalloc()`, and `http_cleanup()` would release them `_afterwards_,` i.e. in the presence of custom allocators, cURL would attempt to use the wrong allocator to release the memory.
>
> A naïve attempt at fixing this would move the call to `curl_global_init()` `_before`_ the config is parsed (i.e. before that call to `slist_append()`).
>
> However, that does not work, as we `_also`_ parse the config setting `http.sslbackend` and if found, call `curl_global_sslset()` which *must* be called before `curl_global_init()`, for details see: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_sslset.html
>
> So let's instead make the config parsing entirely independent from cURL's data structures. Incidentally, this deletes two more lines than it introduces, which is nice.

---

For self-signed certificate, disabling SSL verification globally might be considered a security risk and should be implemented only for testing.

[Referencing the self-signed certificate by `GIT_SSL_CAINFO`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26785963/6309) is more secure.